# Alteração de objeto ModelAndView com Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

```
 @GetMapping("/cadastrarProduto")
 public ModelAndView cadastrarProduto() {
     modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pages/index");
     addObject("produtoEntity", new ProdutoEntity());
     modelAndView;
 }
```

É possível com ajax, alterar os valores dos atributos do objeto ProdutoEntity() passado no modelAndView do exemplo acima?

Comment: voce usa Converter no projeto?

Comment: Em algumas entidades sim, geralmente em atributos do tipo Enum ou LocalDate

Comment: A melhor solução que encontrei foi mandar no submit um @ModelAttribute e capturar o objeto no lado do servidor.